# Post запрос на выполнение JSON-RPC не работает на сайте

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webclient

Явно делаю что то не так. Пытаюсь создать запрос на авторизацию на сайте. Он авторизируется. Но вот дальше json-rpc не работает как быть

```
string linePost = "Page=https%3A%2F%2Fla.mail.ru%2Fdeck&Login=1980IuliaVarlamova@inbox.ru&Password=JTuoPnFt3O&saveauth=1&Domain=mail.ru";
        byte[] sendMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(linePost);
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://auth.mail.ru/cgi-bin/auth");
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Host = "auth.mail.ru";
        req.ContentLength = sendMessage.Length;
        req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "max-age=0");
        req.Headers.Add("Origin", "https://la.mail.ru");
        req.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36 OPR/58.0.3135.132";
        req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3";
        req.Referer = "https://la.mail.ru/deck";
        req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
        req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7");
        req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();


        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"goblins_attempt\",\"params\":{\"cellId\":\"14\"},\"id\":1}");

        HttpWebRequest req1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://la.mail.ru/gw/api/v1/jsonrpc");
        req1.Method = "POST";
        req1.Host = "la.mail.ru";
        req1.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "max-age=0");
        req1.Headers.Add("Origin", "https://la.mail.ru");
        req1.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
        req1.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
        req1.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36 OPR/58.0.3135.132";
        req1.Accept = "application/json, text/plain, */*";
        req1.Referer = "https://la.mail.ru/deck";
        req1.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
        req1.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7");


        req1.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

        Stream requestStream = req1.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас прошлый пример не завелся? Зачем создаете второй подробный вопрос?

Comment: @tym32167 да потому что ничего не понятно вовсе

Comment: @tym32167 нужно чтобы карта открылась там, а она не открывается вовсе

Comment: Какую вы задачу решить хотите в итоге? Рулетка la?

Comment: @tym32167 именно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно в вашей ситуации лично мне не нравится следующее:

1. Куча лишних заголовков.
2. Как то вы странно отправляете JSON на сервер, вы уверены, что он именно в таком виде туда передается?
3. Вы не передаете Cookie коллекцию.

---

### Подготовка

Смотрите, по сути тут все просто. Сайт Lost Ark использует по сути две основные технологии:

1. JWT - Она позволяет авторизовать вас на данном ресурсе. Суть ее в том, что вы на сервер отправляете определенные данные, а он в ответ вам временный ключ доступа, который в последующем надо будет обновить, отправив по новой данные.
2. JSON-RPC - Его задача заключается в обработке запроса, выполнения определенного метода на стороне сервера и передачи результата обратно вам.  Тут вам по сути надо знать какие есть методы у сервера, их параметры запуска, ну и саму версию RPC. Некоторые серверы лояльно относятся к нехватке каких то данных, например конкретно этот сервер допускает отправку всего двух значений (версия и метод).

Исходя из этого идем в Postman (именно туда, Не пишите сразу код! Поймите как все работает!), составляем POST запрос на интересующий нас адрес (указываем адрес, в разделе Body выбираем `Raw` и сбоку тип `JSON`, пишем наш запрос и отправляем.

[image: ErrorPost1]

Но в ответ мы получим следующее:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "error": {
        "code": 1901,
        "message": ""
    }
}
```

Это явно не то, что нам нужно. Идем в `Headers` и начинаем по одному вписывать нужные нам заголовки, начиная с таких, как UserAgent, Referer и так далее, делаем до тех пор, пока ответ от сервера не измениться на нужный нам.
Через некое время мы понимаем, что нужный нам заголовок `Referer` и с ним сервер начинает отдавать нам следующие данные:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "error": {
        "code": 1400,
        "message": "NoAuth"
    }
}
```

То есть по его данным мы не авторизованы. Хорошо, вспоминаем про технологии, которые я описывал выше, вспоминаем про метод авторизации JWT. Он может быть по сути в двух местах - Cookies или Headers. Если посмотреть на запрос через браузер, то видим кучу Cookies, которые отправляются на сервер и одна из них, это `jwtToken`, он то нам и нужен, но если внимательно присмотреться на то, как все эти "печеньки" появляются, то видим то, что ее нам задает сам сервер и опять методом перебора мы понимает, что нужная нам Cookie, это `Mpop`.

Проверяем работу запроса с данной Cookie:

[image: SetCookie1]

Сервер поменял ответ, теперь он выдает следующее:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "error": {
        "code": 1402,
        "message": "NoSDC"
    }
}
```

Тут логически можно предположить, что ему не хватает опять какой то Cookie и судя по названию, это `sdcs`. Добавляем и пробуем:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "attempts": [
            {
                "cell_id": 5,
                "reward_id": 1,
                "order": null
            }
        ],
        "order": "4271563",
        "attemptsCount": 3,
        "availableReward": null,
        "isFailed": false,
        "isCompleted": false
    }
}
```

Наконец мы получили нужный нам результат! Остается это все написать на C#.
Результатом всего этого мы поняли, что нам надо отправить заголовок `Referrer` и две Cookie (`Mpop` и `sdcs`).

### Программирование

Я ооочень сильно ненавижу `HttpWebRequest`, ибо он ужасен по виду, много приходится писать лишнего. По этому я буду писать код на `HttpClient`. Также нам понадобится `Newtonsoft.Json`.

И так, сделаем метод, который отправит все необходимое и вернет нам результат:

```
private async Task<string> SendRequest(Uri uri, Uri referrer = default, ByteArrayContent content = default)
{
    string data;
    var cookies = new CookieContainer();
    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookies })
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri(uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)) })
    {
        cookies.Add(new Uri("https://la.mail.ru"), new Cookie("Mpop", "11:22:33:"));
        cookies.Add(new Uri("https://la.mail.ru"), new Cookie("sdcs", "qqqqqqq"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referrer = referrer;
        var result = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    return data;
}
```

Тут у нас идею следующее:

1. Инициализируется коллекция `CookieContainer`, которая содержит все необходимые наши Cookie (если вы говорите, что авторизацию прошли, то либо передавайте сюда определенные Cookie, либо используйте общую `CookieContainer`).
2. Задается `BaseAddress`, без него лично у меня не заработали Cookie. Адресом является хост запроса (`https://la.mail.ru`).
3. С помощью `cookies.Add()` добавляются к определенному хосту нужные Cookie (повторюсь, если авторизация уже есть, то либо здесь достаем значения из другой коллекции, либо используем общую.).
4. `await client.PostAsync(uri, content);` - отправляем Post запрос с нужным контентом асинхронно.

Вот собственно и все, осталось воспользоваться методом и получить все данные:

Создадим для удобства следующий класс:

```
class LostArkRPC
{
    [JsonProperty("jsonrpc")]
    public string JsonRpc { get; private set; } = "2.0";

    [JsonProperty("method")]
    public string Method { get; set; }
}
```

Этот класс будет служить нам для формирования грамотного JSON запроса.
Далее заполняем этот класс и сериализируем в JSON:

```
var data = new LostArkRPC { Method = "goblins_startSession" };
var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

На этом этапе все данные у нас есть, осталось отправить:

```
var result = await SendRequest(new Uri("https://la.mail.ru/gw/api/v1/jsonrpc"),
    new Uri("https://la.mail.ru/deck"),
    new StringContent(jsonData,
    Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

Все, в `result` у нас будет ответ от сервера с нужными данными.
P.S. Во всем ответе я использовал `goblins_startSession` - это метод статистики, который выводит награды рулетки, сколько ходов осталось и так далее. Открытие карты я думаю вы сделаете по аналогии сами.

---

Набросал тут быстро класс, который будет работать со всем этим делом в удобной форме:

```
class LostArkRPC
{
    public LostArkRPC(string method, object param)
    {
        Method = method;
        Params = param;
    }

    [JsonProperty("jsonrpc")]
    public string JsonRpc { get; private set; } = "2.0";

    [JsonProperty("method")]
    public string Method { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("params")]
    public object Params { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseRoot
{
    public string JsonRpc { get; set; }
    public ResultRoot Result { get; set; }
    public ErrorRoot Error { get; set; }
}

public class ResultRoot
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public int AttemptsCount { get; set; }
    public bool IsFailed { get; set; }
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
}

public class ErrorRoot
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class MailRuManager
{
    private CookieContainer Cookies = new CookieContainer();
    private async Task<string> SendRequest(Uri uri, Uri referrer = default, ByteArrayContent content = default)
    {
        string data;
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = Cookies })
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri(uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)) })
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referrer = referrer;
            var result = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
            data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        return data;
    }

    public async Task Login(string user, string pass)
    {

        // TODO: Некая логика получения Cookie's аккаунта с использованием общего `CookieContainer` 
        // ! Сейчас тут простое заполнение статичными данными.

        Cookies.Add(new Uri("https://la.mail.ru"), new Cookie("Mpop", "111:222:333:"));
        Cookies.Add(new Uri("https://la.mail.ru"), new Cookie("sdcs", "aaaaa"));
    }

    public async Task<ResponseRoot> SendRPC(string method, object param = default)
    {
        var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new LostArkRPC(method, param));
        var response = await SendRequest(new Uri("https://la.mail.ru/gw/api/v1/jsonrpc"),
            new Uri("https://la.mail.ru/deck"),
            new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseRoot>(response);
    }
}
```

Использование примерно следующее:

```
MailRuManager MailRuManager = new MailRuManager();

//Получение наших Cookie's.
await MailRuManager.Login("user", "pass");
//Отправляем запрос к RPC без параметров (метод goblins_startSession - получение статистики)
var userStat = await MailRuManager.SendRPC("goblins_startSession");
//Отправляем запрос к RPC с параметрами (метод goblins_attempt требует номер выбранной карты)
var cellResult = await MailRuManager.SendRPC("goblins_attempt", new { cellId = 2 });
//Выводим на экран кол-во оставшихся ходов (вроде это значение).
Console.WriteLine(userStat.Result?.AttemptsCount);
```

Comment: Вопрос такой, как настроить Postman. Просто мне выдает постоянно There was an error connecting to .

Comment: Его не надо настраивать. Установили и пользуетесь. Что подробно пишется в ошибке?

Comment: Вылажу скриншот

Comment: скриншот в описании выше

Comment: Прочитайте внимательно ошибку, увидите тогда там инструкцию по исправлению (2-й пункт).

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло

Comment: в каком лучше создавать проект, В Веб-приложении ASP.NET (.Net Framework) ??

Comment: Нет понятия "лучше", есть понятие "востребованность под определенную задачу". Я не знаю что вы дальше с этим делать будете. Я обычно пишу ботов для себя (автоматизирую те или иные действия), их я пишу на WPF, ибо там я делаю красивый дизайн. Мне этого достаточно. У вас же, я без понятия какая задача и что вы хотите. Если также бота, то наверно консоль/wpf/winforms, если сайт, то ASP. Учтите кстати, что вы нарушаете правила мейла такими действиями и я не думаю, что ваш сайт проживет долго)

Comment: пытаюсь написать бота на открытие карт :D, кст как взять кеш с авторизированного аккаунта ?

Comment: можете поправить меня ? ошибка, скрин выложил

Comment: правильно я сделал ?

Comment: Вам не кажется, что вы рано взялись за такую задачу? Вы даже основ не знаете. Как вы хотите вызвать не старичный метод в статичном? Переписывайте тогда его в статик (`static async Task<string> SendRequest`).

Comment: Спасибо, а как вывести именно допустим чему равняеться availableReward. А не всю информацию

Comment: @АндрейReyz Я дополнил ответ, написав класс по работе с этим сервисом, там есть и получение определенных данных. Надеюсь это избавит вас от дальнейших вопросов.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98597/discussion-between--reyz-and-evgeniyz).